# Is there a way to get a list of paths in a folder excluding specific folders

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a program that "automatically" creates a .gitignore file.

What I am trying to achieve is to get a list of paths from a specific folder where specific files (extensions) are excluding specific folders.

Let's say I want to find all groovy file paths in a folder (D://Files) and all subfolders (D://Files/SubFiles) but not the subfolder (D://Files/GroovyBackups).

This is what I have so far.

```
if (foldersToIgnore.Count == 0)
    folders = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetFolderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
else
{
    folders = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetFolderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Where(
                            dir =>
                                !foldersToIgnore.Contains(dir)
                                        )
                        .ToList();
}
```

I think the first if statement works fine but as soon as I have folders I want to "ignore" it doesn't

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there is no error, it just doesnt filter the ignored folders

Answer (score 0):

`EnumerateFiles` returns only file paths, not directories.

You need to check the directory of each file:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetFolderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(filePath => !foldersToIgnore.Contains(new FileInfo(filePath).Directory.Name));
```

And you can use case insensitive searching by using a [`StringComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=netcore-3.1#properties), for example:

```
!foldersToIgnore.Contains(new FileInfo(filePath).Directory.Name,
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thank you very much so far, but it seems like i still have the same issue... 
It just wont ignore the folders given.

Comment: @Pibbe how is `foldersToIgnore` defined? Do the paths have trailing slashes?

Comment: Okay i got it now... i didnt put the full path in foldersToIgnore, but just the name of the directory ... It works fine with the full path given. But is there acutally a way to just add the name of the folder to foldersToIgnore instead of the full path ?

Comment: @Pibbe I've updated to use directory name rather than path.